# POSIX Sockets bind() Exercise

Tags: networking, posix

I am trying to solve the following introductory POSIX Sockets exercise:

Write a TCP echo client implementation "to use bind() so that the system selects both the address and port."

(I am assuming "system" refers to the OS.)

I do not understand why a bind() call is necessary when connect() performs the bind in the aforementioned way (correct me if I am incorrect). Also, what values of sin6_addr and sin6_port are necessary for the socket address provided to the bind() call to accomplish this behavior?

Comment: `bind` get an open port, `connect` try to connect to a target `listen` port. They are separated for port reuse. [More info.](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/bindapi.html)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, a `bind` call is not necessary. The system will select the source address and source port when you `connect` if you don't `bind`.

This is an exercise. It's just testing whether you know how to use `bind` this way.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand why a bind() call is necessary when connect()
>   performs the bind in the aforementioned way (correct me if I am
>   incorrect).

You are correct.

> Also, what values of sin6_addr and sin6_port are necessary
>   for the socket address provided to the bind() call to accomplish this
>   behavior?

INADDR_ANY for IPv4. I will leave IPv6 as an exercise for the reader.

You should also specify zero as the port number, then the system will choose.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: this is the opposite of what has been asked. I'm sorry, I thought the question was about the *user* choosing both IP address and port. Thanks to EJP for pointing that out.

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852256/need-a-complete-snippet-example-of-binding-tcp-client-socket) should be what you're looking for.

And this should be the most interesting part:

```
clnt_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
clnt_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
clnt_addr.sin_port = htons(33333);
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clnt_addr,
          sizeof(clnt_addr)) < 0) 
          error("ERROR on binding");
```

In this example the socket is only bound to the desired port (33333) before the connect(), but in your exercise you could change the second line of the above code to:

```
clnt_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");
```

to have the socket bound also on a specific IP address. What matters here is that binding the socket before the connect() sets your endpoint of the TCP/IP communication to use the desired IP address/port. Without the bind() your socket would have been unbounded: the kernel would have chosen the source IP address for you and would have assigned a random source port to your socket.

Comment: That doesn't accomplish the objective of the system selecting the port.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, I completely misunderstood the question. I thought the user had to chose both bind address and port. Well, that's probably because it's the interesting case...